# How to set table header from a div with `display: table` to stick to the top

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make my `.table-header` to stick to the top of the div with `display: table`. I am not allowed to use the `<table>` tags, nor to use `position: sticky` as it is experimental.

So I only am allowed to use `<div>` tags with the matching CSS display (`display: table — table-row — table-cell` ...)

I tried to put `position: relative` on my container and `position: absolute; top: 0;` on the `.table-header`, but it keeps disappearing. How can it stick to the top when scrolling?

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid #CFDFE5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

#super-table {
  display: table;
  padding: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 30px;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #CFDFE5;
}

.table-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="super-table" class="flex-col">
    <div class="table-header row">
      <div>First Name</div>
      <div>Last Name</div>
      <div>Birthdate</div>
      <div>Email</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Neil</div>
      <div class="">Richter</div>
      <div class="">14/08/99</div>
      <div class="">me@neilrichter.com</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Mohamed</div>
      <div class="">Georges</div>
      <div class="">12/05/68</div>
      <div class="">gh@ggggggAzeazeaze.azezae</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Denis</div>
      <div class="">Brogniart</div>
      <div class="">01/05/54</div>
      <div class="">denis.brogniart@ggggG.ggggg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I'm not allowed to use jQuery either.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated solution

Here is a revised proposal based on various ideas, which adds a layer of markup but gives you the desired result. The drawbacks are that you must explicitly set a `(min-)width` on each row (the `nth-child(n)` part) and use `display: block` for some elements to enable `overflow`. I also added a [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) rule to ensure the calculated elements took up space according to their defined dimensions. I added comments in the code to explain further my changes.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  border: 2px solid #CFDFE5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 70vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#super-table {
  display: block; /* Necessary to use overflow */
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #CFDFE5;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Manually setting the width is necessary so the header and the cells columns match */
.row div:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 128px;
}

.row div:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 128px;
}

.row div:nth-child(3) {
  min-width: 128px;
}

.row div:nth-child(4) {
  min-width: 320px;
  width: 100%; /* Ensues the final cell takes up the rest of the available width */
}

.table-header {
  display: block; /* Not necessary (display: table-header-group works too but the parent isn't set to display: table so it feels pointless) here but useful if you convert your <div> to a <tr> */
}

.table-body {
  display: block; /* Necessary to use the overflow property */
  height: calc(100% - 30px); /* Given your rows are set to 30px of height, the final height must be calculated with 100% minus the header  height, or else it takes up a 100% of the parent, so a row gets left out */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="super-table" class="flex-col">
    <div class="table-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div>First Name</div>
        <div>Last Name</div>
        <div>Birthdate</div>
        <div>Email</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Neil</div>
        <div class="">Richter</div>
        <div class="">14/08/99</div>
        <div class="">me@neilrichter.com</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Mohamed</div>
        <div class="">Georges</div>
        <div class="">12/05/68</div>
        <div class="">gh@ggggggAzeazeaze.azezae</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Denis</div>
        <div class="">Brogniart</div>
        <div class="">01/05/54</div>
        <div class="">denis.brogniart@AH.ahhhhhh</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**References:**

1. [Creating Cross-Browser Scrollable s—A CSS-Only Approach](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/11/10/creating-cross-browser-scrollable-tbody/)
2. [CSS Only Fixed Table Headers on CodePen](https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu)

### Original post

Setting `.table-header` to `position: fixed;` will have this effect, but you'll see it move to the top of the viewport. Removing the `top` property places it where it's "supposed" to be (even though it is out of the flow). You can then adjust its position either using `margin` or `transform: translate(X, Y)`. Note that this is a bit hacky but depending on your use, it should turn out okay (note that if you need to scroll to see the table, this won't work as expected - setting the non-header rows in a scrolling element might be more versatile).

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid #CFDFE5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

#super-table {
  display: table;
  padding: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 30px;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #CFDFE5;
}

.table-header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="super-table" class="flex-col">
    <div class="table-header row">
      <div>First Name</div>
      <div>Last Name</div>
      <div>Birthdate</div>
      <div>Email</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Neil</div>
      <div class="">Richter</div>
      <div class="">14/08/99</div>
      <div class="">me@neilrichter.com</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Mohamed</div>
      <div class="">Georges</div>
      <div class="">12/05/68</div>
      <div class="">gh@ggggggAzeazeaze.azezae</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Denis</div>
      <div class="">Brogniart</div>
      <div class="">01/05/54</div>
      <div class="">denis.brogniart@ggggG.ggggg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well yes, that's my problem. It works, but if I scroll the table, and not the content of the table, it will as you said, stay out of the flow, and that's what I don't the table to do. Isn't there any other solution ?

Comment: @NeilRichter See my updated solution which should provide you with what you need.